# How is the number of gems required to finish an upgrade calculated?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In the game we can pay gems to finish an upgrade early. The number of gems is greater the more time that is remaining on the upgrade, but does anyone know exactly how it is calculated?

For example, to skip a 1 day upgrade costs around 200 gems ( I think)
But to skip a 7 day upgrade costs 1000 gems.
Or to skip a 14 day upgrade costs around 1800 gems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is exactly how many gems, `y`, are required to skip `x` seconds. The formula was copied from Wolfgang Graebner's blog post on Gamasutra, titled [Clash of Clans – Time Monetization Formulas Demistifyed](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/WolfgangGraebner/20140402/214504/Clash_of_Clans__Time_Monetization_Formulas_Demistifyed.php).

[image]